# Log File is not getting Generated using log4j.properties & Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, log4j

Hi I have a Spring MVC web based application.
I am trying to add log file. For a individual standalone sample application, I am able to create the Log, But using the same approach in my Project code the Log file is not getting created in my Local folder.
Am I missing some thing as part of Spring MVC Java based configuration?
Please Help.

### log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,CONSOLE,R
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=C:/logs/testlog.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=200KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d - %c - %p - %m%n
```

### WebMVCConfiguration.java

```
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties","classpath:log4j.properties" })
```

Comment: is the log file issue fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

For logging with log4j I use the below configuration in my `web.xml`, it must be registered before `ContextLoaderListener`.

```
<context-param>  
  <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>  
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>  
</context-param>  

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jConfigListener.html):

Bootstrap listener for custom log4j initialization in a web environment. Delegates to Log4jWebConfigurer (see its javadoc for configuration details).